# Discourse analysis about adverbs like "maybe" and "perhaps"

Tags: adverbs

This is a weird question I came across.

It's about adverbs indicating possibility such as "maybe" and "perhaps."

When we use this type of adverb, the sentence becomes hypothetical? Or some parts of it can be true?

---

Example 1:

> A: Where was she?

> B: Maybe she met a **magician who performed awesome magic tricks and is keeping her from arriving on time**.

Because the relative clause is in the past tense and present continuous tense, it makes me think the magician really exists. Do we consider the magician to really exist or do we only consider it a possible thing that might exist?

---

Example 2:

> A: Where will she do?

> B: Maybe she will join **an organization that sells pills that help old people to live forever.**

---

The speaker doesn't know what really happened in example 1 and what will happen in example 2, so the magician and the organization can be both considered hypethetical, but they can also be real instead of being hypothetical, right?

Comment: "Where will she do?" does not make sense.  They can be used with all tenses and do not imply in and of themselves something hypothetical at all.

Comment: _Maybe_, and _perhaps_ can refer to both realistic and imaginary possibilities. "She is late.  Maybe she has been delayed by traffic" is a perfectly realistic scenario.

Comment: There are occasions when it is difficult to distinguish between realistic and imaginary possibilities. Speculate for instance whether a man having dinner on a hotel patio might have been killed by someone falling on top of him. https://www.travelweekly.com.au/article/two-men-die-after-tourist-falls-from-hotel-balcony-landing-on-man-below/

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the tenses in the question and reply do not go together. You should ask

> Where **is** she?

In terms of whether the magician exists, one can't conclude that definitively because the words *maybe* and *perhaps* attach a degree of uncertainty to the sentence. The reply poses a hypothetical scenario.

In your second example, your question should be changed to

> **What** will she do?

The same reasoning as before can be used to justify why the reply also poses a hypothetical scenario.

If you are asking whether such scenarios **can ever happen**, unless the event is beyond the understanding of the natural world, the event most definitely *can* happen. In your first example, however, the reply is a tad facetious.